# Update SQL data but the data contains ' so I get errors

Tags: sql, sql-update, string-constant

I'm trying to update SQL data but it contains `'` so I get errors.

The SQL statement looks like this:

```
UPDATE SystemConfiguration
SET    HeaderScript = '<script> (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],' 
WHERE  ID = 1
```

I tried to replace the quote with `"` but I get error. I also tried without quote I get error as well.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Just double the inner quote.

Comment: will that not affect the code ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to double the single quotes to escape them:

```
UPDATE SystemConfiguration
SET    HeaderScript = '<script> (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({''gtm.start'': new Date().getTime(),event:''gtm.js''});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],' 
WHERE  ID = 1
```